# Stopping a line of execution after it has been excuted in a do-while statement

Tags: c#, do-while

I am taking classes and the teacher asked us if we could figure this out. I've looked now for a few hours and I couldn't find how to do it.

The goal is the get the `displaymenu` to only display once. The app loops so that you can reuse it without exiting. The `displaymenu` displays the user the options to select what they want to do. Now I figure it's not the cleanest code you all have ever seen but I'm still learning - only been doing this for a week. Any other suggestions to it would be appreciated.

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    string choice = "";

    do {
        **displayMenu();**      // only want to display once
        choice = getChoice();                
    }
    while (choice != "10");

    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }      
}

static void displayMenu()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Which shape do you want to work with?"); 
    Console.WriteLine("_____________________________________");
    Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for a circle.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press 2 for an equilateral triangle.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press 3 for a square.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press 4 for a pentagon.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press 5 for a hexagon.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press 6 for a heptagon.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press 7 for a octagon.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press 8 for a nonagon.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press 9 for a decagon.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press 10 to quit.");
}

static string getChoice()
{
    string c = Console.ReadLine();

    if (c == "1")
        circle();
    if (c == "2")
        triangle();
    if (c == "3")
        square();
    if (c == "4")
        polygon(5);
    if (c == "5")
        polygon(6);
    if (c == "6")
        polygon(7);
    if (c == "7")
        polygon(8);
    if (c == "8")
        polygon(9);
    if (c == "9")
        polygon(10);

    return c;
}
```

Comment: Don't place the function call to `displayMenu()` in the loop?

Comment: Thank you!!! Like I said only been doing for a week and the teacher has pound us with so much information I can't even think straight!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to display it once, just put it outside of the loop?

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    string choice = "";

    displayMenu();

    do {
        choice = getChoice();                
    }
    while (choice != "10");

    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Comment: wow i feel really really silly now... i knew it had to be easy... sorry about my spelling lol

Comment: @ChrisComstock if that answer helped than please mark it as Correct ,it will help you and him .

Answer (score 1):

Since choice is numeric, wouldn't it be better to use integer as a input?

```
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        do 
        {
            choice = getChoice();                
        }
        while (choice != 10);
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

To convert string to int could be as easy as this:

```
int choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

But this will create an error if input is not a number. So this is preferred:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        bool isInt;
        int intNumber;
        int choice;

        string stringInput = Console.ReadLine();

        isInt = int.TryParse(stringInput, out intNumber);

        if (!isInt)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input is not a number");
        }
        else
        {
            choice = intNumber;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No it wont, first of all your code is broken. getChoice returns a string not an int. Secondly, the QA have not stated the requirement that choice can only be int. What if choice is \? which is a common expression for getting help? Lastly, your code will actually overwrite the first answer (and it doesnt print the option list) since you do a ReadLine initially which is directly overwritten by your call to getChoice.

Comment: @Polity: I just wanted to demonstrate how to convert from string to int easiest way. And, perhaps, suggest minor change. That's all.